# Python equivalent of ArrayPlot from Mathematica?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, wolfram-mathematica

After much googling, I decided I should just ask this question.

I would like the following functionality, but I can't figure out how to do it at all.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html

Basically, I want to generate a grid map where the color of each pixel is specified by me.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html ?

Comment: I have not. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `matplotlib` package, there is a function [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).